# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложении: «Одно из преступлений против собственности, совершаемых путем обмана, – мошенничество, известно российскому законодательству с периода становления централизованного Московского государства (XVI в.)».

Answer (score 1):

Одно из преступлений против собственности, совершаемых путем обмана, – мошенничество известно российскому законодательству с периода становления централизованного Московского государства (XVI в.).

Нужно убрать запятую после ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕМОГО слова "мошенничество". Приложением здесь является выражение "одно из преступлений против собственности, совершаемых путем обмана". Запятая после приложения завершает причастный оборот и в целом приложение. Тире необходимо, для того чтобы отделить определяемое слово "мошенничество" от осложнённого причастным оборотом приложения. Оно замещает вторую запятую (первая - завершает оборот, вторая должна была выделить приложение).

Answer (score 1):

**Правильно:**

«Одно из преступлений против собственности, совершаемых путем обмана, – мошенничество известно российскому законодательству с периода становления централизованного Московского государства (XVI в.)».

**Правило**

Приложение обособляется с помощью тире, если оно относится к **НАРИЦАТЕЛЬНОМУ  СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНОМУ** (или местоимению) и имеет **дополнительное обстоятельственное значение** (в данном случае его можно заменить деепричастным оборотом (будучи, являясь...).

Если приложение осложнено ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫМ ОБОРОТОМ, то постановка запятых и тире делается **независимым образом**, например: Величайшее из чудес, созданных человеком, – книга воплощает в себе все знания жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Одно из преступлений против собственности, совершаемых путем обмана, мошенничество, известно российскому законодательству с периода становления централизованного Московского государства (XVI в.).

Тире тут не к месту.